# possible to get ng-model's value from DOM to js using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<li data-something="true" ng-model="user.something"></li> 
<li data-something="false" ng-model="user.something"></li>
<li data-something="false" ng-model="user.something"></li> 
<li data-something="true" ng-model="user.something"></li>
```

Say I have a list like above. How can I get the `ng-model` of the `li` which has the property `data-something="true"`? Let's assume I did not use `ng-repeat` in this case. I have no control over the template, so I have to get the data from the DOM using angular.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `ng-attr-data-something="{{ user.something }}"`? Don't see much sense in using `ngModel` on a non-input DOM node

Comment: @AlonEitan I have no control over the DOM.

Comment: how are you coding you spa app if you don't have control over your template?

Comment: @madalinivascu I have to do some hacking on someone's code. It's too messy and I've gave up. Guys please up, I'm one step closer, how to resolve `user.something` using jquery? if i do `$(this).attr('ng-model')` I will get the string `user.something`, not the actual value.

Comment: @JessJordan check the answer. It will help you in better understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Few things you have to keep in mind while working with `data binding` using angularjs.

- `ng-model` only works on `input` & `select`.But you are trying it on `li`
- for `one-way` data binding you have to use `ng-bind` directive.

**Try this :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {something:"Superhero"};
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i=0; i < all.length; i++) {
     var x = all[i].getAttribute("data-something");
     if(x != 'false') {
       var res = all[i].getAttribute("ng-bind");
       var modelValue = angular.element(all[i]).scope();
       console.log(modelValue.user.something);
     }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <li data-something="true" ng-bind="user.something"></li> 
    <li data-something="false" ng-bind="user.something"></li>
    <li data-something="false" ng-bind="user.something"></li> 
    <li data-something="true" ng-bind="user.something"></li>
</div>
```

Comment: Your querying the Dom three times for the li's when you don't need to. Also this will not get the bound value.

Comment: @ste2425 Why downvoted !! I updated the answer check working demo.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. The OP doesn't want the string literal value for the `ng-model` attribute, but the `$scope` value it is bound to with angular. Also you are still querying the DOM more times than you need to. Use `all[i]` within your loop instead of  `document.getElementsByTagName("li")[i]`.

Comment: @ste2425 Thanks for correcting me I updated my answer as per the OP requirement. Can you please review and let me know if anything missing. I want that downvote has been removed from this answer.

Comment: @ste2425 did you reviewed the answer ?